# Getting NameError: free variable referenced before assignment, but cannot see where I've done so

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, pypyodbc

I am trying to create a basic log in frame for my application (not worrying about it being complicated at all, it's for an A Level project). In the checklogin function, I am trying to retrieve the username input by the user, and seeing if it is in the database already, and will add a bit to check that the passwords match later. However I keep getting the error 'NameError: free variable 'userentry' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope'. Looking this error, it says the usual reason is because 'userentry' is being reassigned to later in the same function. However, I am struggling to see where this is the case. Any help will be appreciated.

```
class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="lightgreen")

    def check_login():
        sql = "SELECT Password FROM Player WHERE Username IN (?)"
        parameters = (userentry.get())
        cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
        print(cursor.fetchall())

    for col in range(5):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(col, minsize=50)

    for row in range(7):
        self.grid_rowconfigure(row, minsize=60)

    titlelbl = tk.Label(self,
                        text="Please enter your username and password",
                        font = "Verdana 20 bold",
                        fg="black",
                        bg="lightgreen")

    titlelbl.grid(column=1,
                  row=0,
                  columnspan=3)

    usernamelbl = tk.Label(self,
                           text="Username:",
                           font="Verdana 14",
                           bg="lightgreen")

    usernamelbl.grid(column=1,
                     row=2)

    passwordlbl = tk.Label(self,
                           text="Password:",
                           font="Verdana 14",
                           bg="lightgreen")

    passwordlbl.grid(column=1,
                     row=4)

    signupbtn = tk.Button(self,
                          text="Sign Up",
                          fg="lightgreen",
                          bg="darkgreen",
                          height="3",
                          width="12",
                          command = lambda: controller.show_frame("SignUp"))

    signupbtn.grid(column=3,
                   row=6)

    loginbtn = tk.Button(self,
                         text="Log In",
                         fg="lightgreen",
                         bg="darkgreen",
                         height="3",
                         width="12",
                         command = check_login())

    loginbtn.grid(column=1,
                  row=6)

    userentry = tk.Entry(self)

    userentry.grid(column=3,
                       row=2)

    passentry = tk.Entry(self,
                         show="*")

    passentry.grid(column=3,
                       row=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code

```
loginbtn = tk.Button(self,
                     text="Log In",
                     fg="lightgreen",
                     bg="darkgreen",
                     height="3",
                     width="12",
                     command = check_login())
```

change `command = check_login()` to `command = check_login` (without the parentheses).

`check_login` is the function object. `check_login()` **calls** the function object and evaluates to the return value of the function.

The parentheses tell Python to call the function immediately. Here, when the `tk.Button` is defined, the `userentry` variable is not yet defined. This is why you are getting a `NameError` when `check_login` is called.

So if instead you use `command = check_login` then the `tk.Button` receives the function object, `check_login`, which it can then call later, when the button is pressed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, annoying how things so little can disrupt you. Thanks, onto the next error!